# Error 1062 : Duplicate entry on the slave after a failover

Tags: mysql, database-replication, mysqlbinlog, gtid

**TOPIC MOVED IN DBA SO**

I need a little bit of help for this problem :

I got this error : *Could not execute Write_rows event on table ....; Duplicate entry '16XXXXX-\xE790\XXXXXXX-16XXXXXX' for key 'PRIMARY', Error_code: 1062; handler error HA_ERR_FOUND_DUPP_KEY; the event's master log utilBINLog-bin.000029, end_log_pos 794622875*

A failover happen beetween the master/slave. When the masters became the slave this error happen on the slave.

This setup is using GTID/BINLOG. I would like to avoid skipping this error (Set skip counter to ...) because i think that this may provoke inconsistency in the database.

```
mysql> SHOW SLAVE STATUS \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: 
                  Master_User: 
                  Master_Port: 
                Connect_Retry: 
              Master_Log_File: utilBINLog-bin.000030
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 1590687
               Relay_Log_File: RELAYLog.000002
                Relay_Log_Pos: 168192
        Relay_Master_Log_File: utilBINLog-bin.000029
            Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: No
              Replicate_Do_DB: 
          Replicate_Ignore_DB:
           Replicate_Do_Table:
       Replicate_Ignore_Table:
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                   Last_Errno: 1062
                   Last_Error: Could not execute Write_rows event on table ....; Duplicate entry '16008080-\xE790\-1600000' for key 'PRIMARY', Error_code: 1062; handler error HA_ERR_FOUND_DUPP_KEY; the events master log utilBINLog-bin.000029, end_log_pos 794622875
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 794621018
              Relay_Log_Space: 280882085
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File:
                Until_Log_Pos: 0

Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File:
           Master_SSL_CA_Path:
              Master_SSL_Cert:
            Master_SSL_Cipher:
               Master_SSL_Key:
        Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: 
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error:
               Last_SQL_Errno: 1062
               Last_SQL_Error: Could not execute Write_rows event on table ...; Duplicate entry '16008080-\xE790\-1600000' for key 'PRIMARY', Error_code: 1062; handler error HA_ERR_FOUND_DUPP_KEY; the events master log utilBINLog-bin.000029, end_log_pos 794622875
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
             Master_Server_Id: 101
Master_UUID: a0232561-e21a-11ea-a236-005056af6c92
             Master_Info_File: mysql.slave_master_info
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
      Slave_SQL_Running_State:
           Master_Retry_Count: 86400
                  Master_Bind:
      Last_IO_Error_Timestamp:
     Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp: 
               Master_SSL_Crl:
           Master_SSL_Crlpath:
           Retrieved_Gtid_Set: a0232561-e21a-11ea-a236-005056af6c92:10795159-10967882
            Executed_Gtid_Set: 77818f20-e21a-11ea-b443-005056af4111:1-9605354,
a0232561-e21a-11ea-a236-005056af6c92:1-10795259
                Auto_Position: 1
         Replicate_Rewrite_DB:
                 Channel_Name:
           Master_TLS_Version:
       Master_public_key_path:
        Get_master_public_key: 1
            Network_Namespace:

**Master :** 


**mysql> SHOW MASTER STATUS\G**
*************************** 1. row ***************************
             File: utilBINLog-bin.000030
         Position: 1590687
     Binlog_Do_DB: ....
 Binlog_Ignore_DB:
Executed_Gtid_Set: 77818f20-e21a-11ea-b443-005056af4111:1-9585630,
a0232561-e21a-11ea-a236-005056af6c92:1-10967882
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

When i search for this record in both database, there's no record corresponding to the one display in the errors.

More information - The binlog utilBINLog-bin.000029 is not present on the slave when i display all binary log on the machine :

```
Binary log on slave : 

mysql> SHOW BINARY LOGS;
+-----------------------+------------+-----------+
| Log_name              | File_size  | Encrypted |
+-----------------------+------------+-----------+
| utilBINLog-bin.000001 | 1073742187 | No        |
| utilBINLog-bin.000002 | 1073743074 | No        |
| utilBINLog-bin.000003 | 1073742588 | No        |
| utilBINLog-bin.000004 |  531615680 | No        |
| utilBINLog-bin.000005 |        235 | No        |
+-----------------------+------------+-----------+
5 rows in set (0.06 sec)

Binary logs on master : 

mysql> SHOW BINARY LOGS;
+-----------------------+------------+-----------+
| Log_name              | File_size  | Encrypted |
+-----------------------+------------+-----------+
| utilBINLog-bin.000026 | 1073743702 | No        |
| utilBINLog-bin.000027 | 1073741952 | No        |
| utilBINLog-bin.000028 |  781910611 | No        |
| utilBINLog-bin.000029 | 1073742817 | No        |
| utilBINLog-bin.000030 |    4293615 | No        |
+-----------------------+------------+-----------+
```

A hard failover happen two weeks ago (Server unexpected reboot), is it possible that this transaction was "stuck" since the last failover  ?

It seem's that the executed_GTID_set on the slave (77818f20-e21a-11ea-b443-005056af4111:1-**9605354**) is in advance compare to the current master executed_GTID_set (77818f20-e21a-11ea-b443-005056af4111:1-**9585630**)

How is that possible ?

Some say that i should do a stop slave; reset slave; start slave but according to mysql doc this is not gonna change the executed_GTID_set, or i can inject a fake transaction to tell the slave to pass the problematic transaction but i don't known how i can check if this error concern only one or more transaction.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming, therefore it is off topic here on SO. The DBA sister site of SO offers help in database admin type of questions like this one.

Comment: Thank you i moved this topic to DBA SO